# A possible proof of Brocard’s Problem?

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs, conjectures

Below is perhaps a possible proof of *Brocard’s Problem*, which is a famous problem stating that for $n, m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, there only exists finitely many solutions to the equation $n! + 1 = m^2$ such that only three ordered pairs $(m, n)$ satisfy this equation. Each pair are known as the *Brown Numbers*, and a notable mathematician named Paul Erdós had also conjectured this problem.

$\longrightarrow$ [A possible proof of Brocard’s Problem $-$ Joseph Marx](https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/on-the-finiteness-of-the-brocard-ramanujan-diophantine-equation-pdf.48983/) $\longleftarrow$

I read through it and it does look correct. It mentions that $\sqrt{n!}$ is irrational, even though $\sqrt{0!} = 1^2$ but that case is not important. Since $n$ and $m$ are positive integers, this implies that $n > 0$, so we do not consider this case. Thus, for all the rest of the positive integers $n$, we know that $\sqrt{n!}$ is irrational, therefore $\sqrt{n!} \neq m$ because $m$ is also a positive integer, and all positive integers are rational.

So the question is as follows: Is the supposed proof of Brocard’s Problem actually valid? I can be naive sometimes...

Comment: If you're asking if the proof needs to be self-contained to be a proof, no, proofs can certainly rely on other proofs (and don't need to copy or repeat previous material).  As long as all the statements are true (even if they're not proved in the paper itself), and the logic is valid, the conclusion is also true.  If you're asking to check the proof for correctness directly, that is something I have not done.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ok. I thought there had to be a demonstration of some sort. Thank you for that. I will edit my post.

Comment: I apologize but I cannot access the link and perhaps others cannot either.

Comment: @user328442 I will get to it straight away :)

Comment: This proof is originally from physics forums, as seen [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-possible-proof-for-brocards-problem.619520/). The proof is incorrect, as pointed out by DonAntonio.

Comment: @S.C.B. Wait is it incorrect? I didn’t get it from physics forums. My friend sent it to me and I shared it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "proof" is not very sophisticated and falls apart at the end through a misunderstanding of the basic properties of limits. Starting from

$$\sqrt n! = m O(\sqrt n!),$$

which is just a rearrangement of the initial equation $n!=m^2+1$, the author takes the limit on one side to get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n! = m O(\sqrt n!).$$

This makes little sense. The author then uses the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}O(\sqrt n!)=1$ to claim that there is a contradiction, since $\sqrt n! \neq m$. This is not how limits work.

Comment: Ok. It made sense to me at the limit part of how $n$ cannot tend to $\infty$... but if it doesn’t make sense... then I’m not making sense haha. Congratulations!! $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$ Oh and btw, how *do* limits work then, particularly in this case? What would result from this case if we used the limit properly?

Comment: @user477343 It was a nice try. :) At a glance, I think that the same (fallacious) reasoning would lead to a proof that there are only finitely many Pythagorean triples: start with $a^2+b^2=c^2$, divide by $b^2$ to get $(a/b)^2+1=(c/b)^2$, and see what happens.

Comment: Haha well I know Euclid proved there are infinitely many Pythagorean triples, so thank you for explaining to me :)

Comment: @user477343 Regarding limits, have a look at the line
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n! = m O(\sqrt n!).$$
The left side diverges to infinity, while the right side is an expression that depends on $m$ and $n$, so that doesn't work. If you're going to take limits, take them on both sides (similar to taking square roots, say). So you should get:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n! = \lim_{n\to\infty}m O(\sqrt n!).$$
Now the left side diverges to infinity, while the right side simplifies to $m$. So all that we've discovered is that as $n$ tends to $\infty$, so does $m$, which isn't so surprising.

Comment: You should have included that in your answer! Anyway, thank you so much still. I kind of figured that out after you explained to me before since the paper said $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n!} = 1$ and that’s when I realised it didn’t make sense, but I wouldn’t have without your help :)

Comment: Hi. What are the best known results of the Brocard's problem

Comment: @Théophile [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316110458_SOLVING_THE_BROCARD_PROBLEM) is another "proof" by a high school student. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire At a glance, based on the level of writing (e.g., needing to prove that odd primes are congruent to $\pm1$ modulo $6$), and considering that the problem has eluded professional mathematicians such as Ramanujan, I would wager that this "proof" is incorrect.

Comment: @Théophile It seems that they've only considered when $m$ is prime and no other.

Comment: They also copied the introduction from [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/galway.pdf)... so its validity is increasingly suspicious

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Hmmm... I wouldn't waste too much more time on it then!

Comment: @Théophile It's because I'm working on the problem as well and I'm looking to see if anyone's used my method yet. If so I can continue from where they have finished.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Ah, I see. Well, I'm certainly no expert on Brocard's problem, so I can only wish you good luck. :)